# The 'for' attribute in labels html forms

Tags: html, forms, for-loop

How essential is this my forms are generated via a cms so unless I use jquery there is no way I can find the id of the element to put in here.

How important are these attributes?

Comment: then you could write `<label>Your label <input /></label>`

Answer (score 1):

Label elements are very good for accessibility (they make it easier for screen readers to handle forms and give bigger click targets).

They are useless unless they are actively associated with a form control.

You can associate them using either a `for` attribute or by placing the control *inside* the label. So do one or the other.

Support for `for` is better though.

(And if your CMS can't be edited to generate marching `for` and `id` attributes, then it really isn't very good.)

Answer (score 0):

The `[for]` attribute is necessary for accessibility when the `<label>` doesn't have an implicit control.

If you're unable to change the server-side code such that it correctly generates `[for]`attributes, then you should change the structure so that the control is nested within the `<label>`:

```
<label>
    Label for the control
    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
</label>
```

As per [the HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-label-element):

> If the `for` attribute is not specified, but the `label` element has a labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the `label` element's labeled control.